# Failed to get some IDs from PC, with C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem getting all the id's that I request from the PC hardware but it only shows me some. I have been like this for 2 days without knowing why.

My windows form code to call the ids:

```
OSVer.Text = RegHelper.readStringValue(RegistryValues.LicOsVerKey(), RegistryValues.LicOsVerValue());
WuID.Text = RegHelper.readStringValue(RegistryValues.LicWUIDKey(), RegistryValues.LicWUIDValue());
```

Class RegHelper:

```
internal class RegHelper
{
    public static bool isKeyExist(RegistryHive hive, string key)
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, RegistryView.Default);
            result = (Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key) != null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string readStringValue(string regKey, string regValue)
    {
        string result;
        try
        {
            result = (string)Registry.GetValue(regKey, regValue, "");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string[] readMultiStringValue(string regKey, string regValue)
    {
        string[] array = new string[0];
        string[] result;
        try
        {
            result = (string[])Registry.GetValue(regKey, regValue, array);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = array;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int readDwordValue(string regKey, string regValue)
    {
        int result;
        try
        {
            result = (int)Registry.GetValue(regKey, regValue, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void writeValue(string regKey, string regValue, int valData)
    {
        try
        {
            Registry.SetValue(regKey, regValue, valData, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void writeValue(string regKey, string regValue, string valData)
    {
        try
        {
            Registry.SetValue(regKey, regValue, valData, RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    internal static void writeValue(string v1, string v2, object p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Class RegistryValues:

```
public static string buildLabExKey()
{
    return "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
}

public static string buildLabExValue()
{
    return "BuildLabEx";
}
```

I have other classes that I do not know what they are for, but in the program where I am guiding, they show them all.

Comment: don't swallow exceptions. they are super helpful.

Comment: We don't allow requests for off-site help (*remote access* to your computer), and it's foolish to allow just anyone from the internet to access your computer remotely. Do you have any idea what damage that person could do to your computer or what information they could steal from you? If the question can't be answered here using text in the space provided below for that purpose, it's not appropriate for this site.

Comment: there seems to be no relationship between the code at the top , LicOsVerKey, and the code at the end, buildLabExKey